# Error codes when debugging in Visual Studio 2013 for C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-errors, visual-studio-2013

My C++ code in Visual Studio Express 2013 (code replicated from a programming book I was using) generates a whole bunch of errors too long to list here... But each error is the same problem:

> "Cannot find or open the PDB file."

An example of one file it was trying to find/open is: `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll`

Anyone got any suggestions? I'm a total newbie so please use plain words!
Cheers.

Comment: No problem, just ignore these messages, unless you need to debug Windows system libraries.

Comment: @AlexFarber: mostly correct, although sometimes the debugger is not able to construct a proper stack trace without them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you build a binary with VS, VS creates a program database for it.  When debugging a process, VS searches for debug symbols next to the binary.

As long as you don't need these symbols (to set a breakpoint in e.g. `WaitForSingleObject` or so), you don't need the .pdb either.

However, when the debugger tries to construct a call stack, it often *does* need the symbols (it will tell you that 'frames might not be correct').  In that case, you can tell [VS to retrieve the microsoft program databases from the Microsoft Symbol Servers](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311503).

Note: when all this symbol-loading slows down your process, there are settings to disable automatically loading them.